# Check if array has element(s) from another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays `A = [0,1,2]` and `B = [2,1,0]`. How to check if a number in A is present in B?

Comment: `A.every( e => B.includes(e) )`

Comment: Or `A.some(e => B.includes(e))` if you meant "any number of A present in B".

Comment: @PranavCBalan includes is not ES6, but ES7

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**NOTE: `includes` is not ES6, but ES2016** [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Specifications). This will break if you transpile ES6 only.

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method(to iterate and check all element passes the callback function) with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method(to check number present in B).

```
A.every( e => B.includes(e) )
```

```js
const A = [0, 1, 2],
  B = [2, 1, 0],
  C=[2, 1];

console.log(A.every(e => B.includes(e)));
console.log(A.every(e => C.includes(e)));
console.log(C.every(e => B.includes(e)));
```

---

To check a single element present in the second array do:

```
A[0].includes(e) 
//^---index
```

Or using [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method, for older browser.

```
A[0].indexOf(e) > -1
```

---

Or in case you want to check at least one element present in the second array then you need to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method(to iterate and check at least one element passes the callback function).

```
A.some(e => B.includes(e) )
```

```js
const A = [0, 1, 2],
  B = [2, 1, 0],
  C=[2, 1],D=[4];

console.log(A.some(e => B.includes(e)));
console.log(A.some(e => C.includes(e)));
console.log(C.some(e => B.includes(e)));
console.log(C.some(e => D.includes(e)));
```

Comment: That's supposing he meant "*all* numbers in A are present in B", which I'm not sure he was.

Comment: Be warned that this will _not_ work for arrays containing arrays/objects.

Comment: Also will be incorrect if A is a subset of B. E.g. `A = [0], B = [0,1,2]`

Comment: @VasilDininski : agreed, plus this doesn't work if you've A = [1,2,3,3] , B = [1,2,3] , coz it's a normal comparison of variable exist or not !!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a self defined function I use to compare two arrays. Returns true if array elements are similar and false if different. Note: Does not return true if arrays are equal (array.len && array.val) if duplicate elements exist.

```js
var first = [1,2,3];
var second = [1,2,3];
var third = [3,2,1];
var fourth = [1,3];
var fifth = [0,1,2,3,4];

console.log(compareArrays(first, second));
console.log(compareArrays(first, third));
console.log(compareArrays(first, fourth));
console.log(compareArrays(first, fifth));

function compareArrays(first, second){
    //write type error
    return first.every((e)=> second.includes(e)) && second.every((e)=> first.includes(e));
}
```

Comment: first and third are different - this solution doesn't account for order

Comment: Yes like i said Note: Does not return true if arrays are equal (array.len && array.val) if duplicate elements exist. you need to add a bit more code to of use a different alogorithm to detect exact equality. A combination of Array.every() with Array.findIndex() should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is to actually compare the array, the following will also account for duplicates

```
const arrEq = (a, b) => {
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false
  }
  const aSorted = a.sort()
  const bSorted = b.sort()


  return aSorted
    .map((val, i) => bSorted[i] === val)
    .every(isSame => isSame)
}
```

Hope this helps someone :D

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know whether A and B has same entries, simply

```
JSON.stringify(A.concat().sort()) === JSON.stringify(B.concat().sort())
```

Note:
If there are `null` and `undefined` in each array, it will be true. Because `JSON#stringify` converts `undefined` to `null`.

```
JSON.stringify([null].concat().sort()) === JSON.stringify([undefined].concat().sort()) 
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A.length === B.length && A.every(e => B.includes(e))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.